# C# Byte array index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

Dear developers why i get error? (index was outside the bounds of the array)

[image: Debug info]

Comment: Because your MagicList is 300 element byte array, and `100 * 3 = 300` that is greater than 299 - maximal valid index.

Comment: FYI You can reuse a stringbuilder with .clear

Comment: Eugene, i create array for 450 elements, how on screen, where problem? or C# have max. valid index for byte array?

Comment: @user3000633 Your `autos` directly say that your array is `byte[300]`.  You have created it as `byte[450]`, but `GetAsBinary` method result rewrites the original array with smaller.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you create `MagicList` as an array of 450, but in the debugger, it says it's an array of 300. This is because the array you explicitly create is never actually used. It's immediately replaced by the array returned by `GetAsBinary`. That array is only 300 bytes long, and that's why your code fails. Your loop exit condition must take the actual array size into account, instead of assuming the size. The following code shows a way you could avoid the problem.

```
byte[] magicList = DBLite.dbMu.GetAsBinary("magicList");
DBLite.dbMu.Close();
for (int i = 0; i < magicList.Length/3; i++) {
```